# Serialize HashMap into Redis Using Kryo

Tags: java, redis, kryo

I am trying to under how `Kryo` serlization works. I have a very large HashMap which I would like to push into `Redis`. The HashMap is:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Set<Long>>> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

What is the fastest way to serialize into `Redis` ?

**Option 1: Directly into Redis?**

I see that you can use `Kryo` like:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.register(HashMap.class);
Output output = //For Redis what would the output be ?
kryo. writeObject(output, cache)
```

But I am confused as to what `Output` should be when using `Redis`.

**Option 2: Via a byte array?**

I have also seen that the following maybe possible:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.register(HashMap.class);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Output output = new Output(stream);
kryo.writeObject(output, cache);
output.close();
byte[] buffer = stream.toByteArray();
jedis.set("Test", buffer);
```

But this seems inefficient to me as I am effectively "cloning" my large cache into a byte array.

What is an efficient approach for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no Redis output for Kryo. Jedis has only `byte[]` and `String` APIs so you can't use wrapped/pooled buffers.

Using Kryo is possible already with [redisson](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson) as they provide a Kryo codec which uses `ByteBuffer`s. Alternatively, you could also use [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) which is a low-level Redis driver providing also a [codec API](http://redis.paluch.biz/docs/api/releases/latest-4.x/com/lambdaworks/redis/codec/RedisCodec.html) using `ByteBuffer`.